# How to maintain stock_on_quantity on item_master table whenever an item is purchased or sold?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

Minimum 3 stocks in item_master table should be maintained.

Table: item_master

```
create table item_master
(
    item_no number(5) primary key,
    name varchar(10),
    stock_on_hand number(5) default 0
);
```

Table: item_detail

```
create table item_detail
(
    item_no number(5) references item_master,
    operation varchar(10) check(operation in('Sales','Purchase')),
    quantity number(5)
);


insert into item_master values(101,'Chair',5);
insert into item_master values(102,'Sofa',4);
insert into item_master values(103,'Table',6);
```

I have written this trigger for maintaining minimum 3 stocks.

```
    create or replace trigger tristk
    before insert or update or delete on item_master
    for each row
    declare 
        stk number(5);
    begin
select stock_on_hand into stk from item_master where item_no = :new.item_no;

        if(stk<=3) then 
            raise_application_error(-20000,'Not enough stock');    
        end if;
    end;
    /
```

I have written Another trigger to automatically update item_master whenever I insert or update or delete in item_detail

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER triitem AFTER
    INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON item_detail
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE item_master
    SET
        stock_on_hand =
            CASE :new.operation
                WHEN 'Sales'      THEN stock_on_hand -:new.quantity
                WHEN 'Purchase'   THEN stock_on_hand +:new.quantity
            END
    WHERE item_no =:new.item_no;
END;
/
```

Comment: So, why not create the other Trigger? you have already written one. What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: I have written this trigger bt error is coming of table SCOTT.ITEM_DETAIL is mutating, trigger/function may not see it at "SCOTT.TRIITEM", line 6. Error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT TRIITEM'

Answer (score 0):

The error with your second trigger is that you are not supposed to run queries on the trigger owner as database has not seen the changes done by your dml that raised the trigger.

I would recommend you to avoid Triggers to implement business logic altogether if possible.

The solution to your problem is to simply refer to all the columns using the `:NEW` prefix. I have also simplified your update statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER triitem AFTER
    INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON item_detail
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE item_master
    SET
        stock_on_hand =
            CASE :new.operation
                WHEN 'Sales'      THEN stock_on_hand -:new.quantity
                WHEN 'Purchase'   THEN stock_on_hand +:new.quantity
            END
    WHERE item_no =:new.item_no;
END;
/
```

Comment: Sir this worked only 1 time... And i have to update item_master for all the 3 items

Comment: Automatically item_master should get updated whenever item is purchased or sold

Comment: @JaicyJoseph : This answers the question you asked and you may accept the answer if it works for you.. You should make an attempt to fix others in a similar way. If you face another problem, post it as a new question separately.

Comment: Wr is the problem in my trigger?

Comment: @JaicyJoseph : I am sorry to say this but you have created a mess of this whole post. Firstly, I gave you an answer which you have put into the question itself. Also, You have not deleted those answers which you wrote. I request you to delete your question and start a new question providing only the required details.

Comment: Ok sir.. really sorry... Bt i can't delete my answers... I tried it. I will make it as a new question

Comment: Sir i did the changes. Can u just see it now.?